# adb reboot recovery error: closed

Tags: adb, samsung, boot-loop

I have an old Samsung Tab 3 (NT210) that is bricked after not being used for a few years - it gets stuck at the Samsung logo screen after being turned on. However, I am able to boot into the recovery screen.

I have been looking at various online solutions and most seem to suggest flashing custom recovery and ROM to solve this issue. I have managed to find a twrp recovery image and a custom ROM for the device, and had decided to load them into the device via adb. I followed the instructions from this webpage: https://how2do.org/how-to-use-adb-sideload-to-install-roms-updates-restore/

I first ensured that my device was recognised as shown:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
5200ee695a69c000        sideload
```

However, the process will fail at 'adb reboot recovery' as I keep getting the following error:

```
adb reboot recovery
error: closed
```

Further research into this problem showed that likely cause of this error is because the device is using **stock recovery**. I can also confirm that the device has not been rooted before. Commands such as adb shell or adb usb will also return the "error: closed" error message.

Is it still possible to root or salvage the device? I can still charge the device and boot it into recovery or download mode, but that's about it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello Strider1994. You've got the instructions all wrong (adb commands don't work in stock recovery). First, list your priority. Do you want the device to be able to boot into Android or you want to root the device whatever the state your Android is in? Second, forget about stock recovery if you want to root the device as it is useless (other than to factory reset the device and sideload stock ROM). Third, in any case you would choose you are likely to lose your existing data in the device so be ready for that. Fourth, proceed to Uncle Web with your priority in mind.

Comment: The sideload mode is a special adb mode only used by recovery roms. It is not a full adb connection, instead it can be only used to provide a ROM image via USB and flash it. Therefore other commands except `adb sideload` do not work.